# How to create heatmap in Python using OSMnx and a list of values corresponding to the graph's nodes?

Tags: simulation, networkx, heatmap, pyhook, osmnx

I've built a simulation model of pedestrians walking on a network using OSMnx and one of the simulation's outputs is a list "Visits" that is corresponding to the nodes in `NodesList = list(Graph.nodes)`.
How can I create an heatmap using those lists and OSMnx?

For example:

```
NodesList[:5]
Output: [1214630921, 5513510924, 5513510925, 5513510926, 5243527186]

Visits[:5]
Output: [1139, 1143, 1175, 1200, 1226]
```

P.S.
the type of heatmap is not important (Nodes size, nodes color, etc.)

Comment: I have the same need plus heatmap is required, anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Since you specified the type of heatmap is not important, I have come up with the following solution.

```
import osmnx as ox
address_name='Melbourne'

#Import graph
G=ox.graph_from_address(address_name, distance=300)

#Make geodataframes from graph data
nodes, edges = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G, nodes=True, edges=True)

import numpy as np
#Create a new column in the nodes geodataframe with number of visits
#I have filled it up with random integers
nodes['visits'] = np.random.randint(0,1000, size=len(nodes))

#Now make the same graph, but this time from the geodataframes
#This will help retain the 'visits' columns
G = ox.save_load.gdfs_to_graph(nodes, edges)

#Then plot a graph where node size and node color are related to the number of visits
nc = ox.plot.get_node_colors_by_attr(G,'visits',num_bins = 5)
ox.plot_graph(G,fig_height=8,fig_width=8,node_size=nodes['visits'], node_color=nc)
```

[image]

Comment: I get this error:
AttributeError: module 'osmnx' has no attribute 'save_load'
Which version of osmnx are you using?

Comment: You are right. This code was based on an older version of OSMnx. As per the current version, you may use the following...

Comment: G = ox.utils_graph.graph_from_gdfs(nodes, edges)